# writing a wrapper for fwprintf

Tags: c++, unicode, stringstream, printf

I'm trying to write a wrapper for `fwprintf`. I'm using a `wstringstream` to capture a formatted `va_list` and then use the actual `fwprintf` to print to file. For some reason, instead of a nice unicode string, I am getting garbled numbers.

Can anyone help?

```
void WriteToLog(wchar_t *message, ...)
{
FILE * pFile;

if (_wfopen_s (&pFile, SZ_LOG_FILE_PATH,L"a") != 0)
{
    display_error_message(-1, L"Could not open log file.", IsSilent, MB_ICONSTOP);
    return;
}

std::wstringstream buffer;
va_list args;
va_start(args, message);
buffer << vwprintf(message, args);
va_end(args);

fwprintf(pFile, buffer.str().c_str());

fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you've got something perfectly good (wstringstream) and then you completely blow it with hideous printf, variable arguments, non-const pointers?

Comment: Why not use `vfwprintf` directly, and avoid the `std::wstringstream` and `vwprintf` detour ? Or better yet, just use C++ streams ?

Comment: As if you haven't got enough troubles, there's a nice undefined behaviour and a security bug in there. What if your buffer contains a `'%'` character? Never use a string that you do not control as a format string for any prinf-style function.

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments. I should I have mentioned that I am NOT a C++ programmer, but had to implement a few mild extensions to en existing project.
DeadMG - thanks for the advice, I'll use const pointers.
Sander - vfwprintf was just what I needed, thank you!!!
n.m. - this is an internal function and the message parameter WILL probably contain a '%' character, because this is a wrapper for fprintf. Thanks for the advice though, I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You're outputting integers to the stream, and you're baffled that after that the stream contains (decimal specifications of) integers.

Consider, your code

```
buffer << vwprintf(message, args);
```

is equivalent to

```
int const x = vwprintf(message, args);
buffer << x;
```

Do you perhaps now see how you get your actual results?

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I just wrote this in the comment above - I am not a C++ programmer, I just had to do some re-writes on old code (I come from the much simpler world of C#). 
I must say I don't understand the problem - << redirects stdout, does it not? and vwprintf prints to std out... does it not?

Comment: As Alf points out, vwprintf returns the number of characters written.  Which you are saving in a buffer and then printing which I doubt is what you want...

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is generally terrible (much better would be for instance to expose a logging output stream, or any number of Boost logging facilities), but if you really must go through with it, let's see how to fix this. First off, `vwprintf` prints to the standard output, not to a string, so first of all do read up the documentation of your basic building block functions. The closest thing to something useful would be `vswprintf`, which prints to a wide string. We still need to impose an arbitrary size limit:

```
wchar_t buf printbuf[1024];
vswprintf(printbuf, 1024, message, args);

buffer << std::wstring(buffer);
```

You'd still have to add some sort of error handling in the event that your buffer is too short.

Comment: thanks for the advice and the honest advice :-)

I ended up using vfwprintf and it works like a charm.

thank you!

Comment: Cool, no worries. If you already have a file pointer, then `vfwprintf` indeed sounds like the most direct solution.